# Inserting checkbox value into database

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

How to insert checkbox values into database without making the id not incremented.

Here is my code:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=sizeof($checkbox); $i++){
    $sql2="INSERT INTO tbl_training VALUES ('".$checkbox[$i]."')";
    $result2=mysql_query($sql2);
}
```

This code needs auto incremented id to avoid errors.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Answer (score 0):

specify auto-increment column in your database table

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

**e.g. :**

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
     id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     ..
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

and then your insert query will work

Comment: thanks, but my problem is when id is not in auto_increment I got errors. and my needed scenario in the database is 1 (checkboxvalue) 1 (checkboxvalue) 2 (checkboxvalue) 2 (checkboxvalue) 2 (checkboxvalue) something like that. sorry for the illustrations.

Answer (score 0):

If your `id` is set to `auto_increment` in MySQL, you can leave the it empty, like -

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO tbl_training (id,checkboxes) VALUES ('','".$checkbox[$i]."')";
```

Comment: thanks, but my problem is when id is not in auto_increment I got errors. and my needed scenario in the database is 1 (checkboxvalue) 1 (checkboxvalue) 2 (checkboxvalue) 2 (checkboxvalue) 2 (checkboxvalue) something like that. sorry for the illustrations.

Comment: What is your table structure?